# remove cursor on focus textbox

Tags: jquery, html

I want to remove cursor form a textbox on focus.When I click the textbox it shows cursor.I want to remove the cursor after I clicked the textbox

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $(function(){
        $('#edit-field-date-value-value-datepicker-popup-0').blur();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="edit-field-date-value-value-datepicker-popup-0" name="field_date_value[value][date]" value="" size="20" maxlength="30" class="form-text hasDatepicker date-popup-init">
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be annoying, an input the user can't use? Why not just remove it.

Comment: I have date picker in input box as per design I have to remove cursor

Comment: You'll have to be clearer, do you just want to hide the cursor, or blur the input on focus. You know jQuery's datepicker can be set on an element that isn't an input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `color: transparent;` to make the cursor hidden and `outline: none;` to get rid of the focused border.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $('#edit-field-date-value-value-datepicker-popup-0').blur();
  });
});
```

```css
#edit-field-date-value-value-datepicker-popup-0:focus {
  color: transparent;
  //and 
  //outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="edit-field-date-value-value-datepicker-popup-0" name="field_date_value[value][date]" value="" size="20" maxlength="30" class="form-text hasDatepicker date-popup-init">
```

Comment: But this way you can't see what you're actually typing ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done purely with CSS:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $(function(){
        $('#edit-field-date-value-value-datepicker-popup-0').blur();
    });
});
```

```css
#edit-field-date-value-value-datepicker-popup-0{
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 gray;
}
#edit-field-date-value-value-datepicker-popup-0:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="edit-field-date-value-value-datepicker-popup-0" name="field_date_value[value][date]" value="" size="20" maxlength="30" class="form-text hasDatepicker date-popup-init">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cursor:none on focus.

```
#edit-field-date-value-value-datepicker-popup-0:focus{
    cursor:none;
}
```